# Why does my image not respect the parent div size?

Tags: html, css, image, class

I am trying to make a website section where I have some text to the side of an image, but my image stretches out the parent div instead of taking up 100% of the height like specified

In my understanding the height I specified in .more-info-section should be carried down to the child div .info-image-container and then carried down to the image, but when I add the image it stretches its parent .info-image-container, while the height of .more-info-section remains the same 30rem

```css
.more-info-section {
  height: 30rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.info-image-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.info-image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.info-info {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="more-info-section">
  <div class="info-image-container">
    <img class="info-image" src="Images/bag2.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="info-info">
    <h1>The Header</h1>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I also add `height:30rem` explicitly to .info-image-container then the image does scale down, but it doesn't crop like it should because of the `object-fit:cover` . So clearly I'm doing something wrong but for the life of me I cannot figure out what it is

Answer (score 3):

So your image container is using `100%` for the height and width. `100%` is relative to its nearest ancestor, being the `more-info-section` where there is no width defined. You should set your image to `height: 100%;` and remove the width. Use `max-width: 100%;` instead so it resizes responsively and will fit in the `30rem` container.

You can see now it fits in the container:

[image]

You can view the working version of that example here:

```css
.more-info-section {
  height: 30rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.info-image-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.info-image {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.info-info {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="more-info-section">
  <div class="info-image-container">
    <img class="info-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="info-info">
    <h1>The Header</h1>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This second example shows that `height: 100%;` exceeds `30rem`, and `height: inherit;` would be your solution for it to fill only the height of the parent.

```css
.more-info-section {
  height: 30rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.info-image-container {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

.info-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.info-info {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="more-info-section">
  <div class="info-image-container">
    <img class="info-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
  </div>
  <div class="info-info">
    <h1>The Header</h1>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `max-width` and `max-height` properties to manage the size of the image. These properties, as the name suggests, specify the maximum width and height of an element. Note that if the image is smaller than the `max-width` and `max-height` property, then `max-width` and `max-height` have no effect.